# Confusing result from a small code in Java

Tags: loops, java

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        for(; x < 6; x++) {
            x = x * x;
        }
        System.out.printf("%d", x);
    }
}
```

I have been learning java for months. What I'm amazed I have found this kind of a set question in sololearn and I have proved myself the answer is 26.
   I understand the normal for loop how it works, but I don't understand this kind of format.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to familiarize yourself with a debugger. The "surprise" stems from modifying the loop variable, as burnabyRails notes, something you should (usually) avoid doing. (As an alternative, read up on how `for` loops are specified in Java, and work through the code step by step.)

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Please let me know, I can help more if it was not

Answer (score 2):

Since `x` is both the counter of the loop that is being incremented at every iteration, and it is also modified within the same loop it might be a bit confusing for a starter.

> Starting with value `1`, you go into the loop, since `1 < 6`, you
>   square the `1 * 1 = 1`, then next iteration of loop, where you get
>   `x++`, thus `1 + 1 = 2`, again square, `2 * 2 = 4`, again `x++`, 
>   `4 + 1 = 5`, again squared `5 * 5 = 25`.

Then the confusing part as I understand comes into play, you are confused why we got a final `x++`. The iteration when `x` became `25`, was when we went in with `x = 5`, which is `< 6`, then after the statement within the loop is executed, you then do the increment/decrement for the next iteration, namely `25 + 1 = 26`, and only after that we leave the loop and get your mysterious result!

Check the following image, and follow it with the code using a pen-paper, then a debugger.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop in Java has 3 parts, initialization, condition and afterthought, **all three being optional**, that means you can do loops like `for(;x > 10;)` and `for(int x = 0 ;; ++x)`.

for example:

```
for(;;){
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

will print "test" forever because `for(;;)` is equal to `while(true)` since the parts of the `for` loop of the for are not beign used.

In this specific code, the variable `x` is used outside the `for` because will be printed once the loop finish, if the variable is declared in the initialization part, when the loop ends the variable will go out of scope thus causing unwanted results.

**tl;dr**: the loop is normal and has a normal "format", only is not using the initialization part of the `for`

[Check Traditional for-loops on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#Traditional_for-loops)